# Experience of Sukkos, Pesach or Shevuos in Yerushalayim

Tags: sources-mekorot, chagim-holidays

Do we have any historical accounting in any seifer about the Jewish people spending Sukkos, Pesach or Shevuos in Yerushalayim?